# pass NULL to SQL query

Tags: java, sql

I am getting null result through QueryRunner, but if I execute the query I am getting rows retruned in SQL developer.

```
ProductId: null
SKUCode:61334a

ServiceResult<List<T>> market = service.getMarketProduct(null,'61334a');
```

The above mentioned service code will hit DAO layer shown below:

```
return QueryHelper.queryList( GET_PRODUCTS, new Object[]{ 0 == ProductId? null : ProductId, SKUCode}, this.cs, CPCMarketProductVO.class );

GET_PRODUCTS= SELECT * FROM table WHERE ProductId= nvl(?, ProductId) AND prd_id = nvl(?, SKUCode).
```

Can someone please tell me why I am getting null results through java code and how results are returned in SQL developer.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to fetch in your table? Can't get what `NVL` is there for. `NVL` will substitute a null value with the proposed parameter, why use it in a where clause? Can you show your working SQL query and result?

Comment: Also, `GET_PRODUCTS` is a string? If so with `WHERE ProductId= nvl(?, ProductId)` you're asking something like _select where column ProductId equals ProductId java value when the value is not null, else the string "ProductId" when ProductId java value is null._

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused in [what `NVL` function is for](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm). Pratically it is useful when the query returns a `NULL` value and you are doing some kind of [operation or aggregate function in it](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-nvl.html). Instead you are using it to create the request.

Probably you should change the `GET_PRODUCTS` query in something like

```
GET_PRODUCTS= SELECT * FROM table WHERE ProductId = ? AND prd_id = ?
```

When you substitute the `?` values with the `new Object[]{ 0 == ProductId? null : ProductId, SKUCode}` and values `ProductId = null, SKUCode = 61334a` the query becomes:

```
GET_PRODUCTS= SELECT * FROM table WHERE ProductId = null AND prd_id = 61334a
```

returning an empty result set, which should be correct if ProductId is not nullable (I assume is a primary key).

If you instead have `NULL` ProductIds in your table the result set may not be empty.

Comment: So you changed the query in `GET_PRODUCTS= SELECT * FROM table WHERE ProductId= nvl(?, 0) AND prd_id = nvl(?, 0)` ? If so, wouldn't be better to modify the object creation in `new Object[]{ null == ProductId? 0: ProductId, null == SKUCode? 0 : SKUCode}` and the query in what I proposed in the answer?